# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This problem is - i think - pointing to a deleted image, but there is definitely no image called `missing` in the app.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):

                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    pins GET    /pins(.:format)                pins#index
                         POST   /pins(.:format)                pins#create
                 new_pin GET    /pins/new(.:format)            pins#new
                edit_pin GET    /pins/:id/edit(.:format)       pins#edit
                     pin GET    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#show
                         PATCH  /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#update
                         PUT    /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#update
                         DELETE /pins/:id(.:format)            pins#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                              pages#home
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but there is definitely no image called missing in the app.

... and that is the problem!

Your app is looking for a picture to show, if no image has been uploaded.
This is defined in your model, where the attachment (via paperclip or carrierwave) is defined.

see the Quick Start of e.g. [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png" # <= you see ?
end
```

You need to place an image called `missing.png` for each different *style* (here `medium` and `thumb`) defined in your `app/assets/images/:style` folder(s). This will then be handled by the asset pipeline. 
If you only want to upload the `missing`-images to S3, you need to define a bucket there, add folders for each defined *style* and reference them via absolute path like this:

```
:default_url => "https://YOURBUCKET.amazons3.com/:style/missing.png"
```

If you upload all your user uploaded content to S3, i recommend reading the excellent documentation on [Paperclip::Storage::S3](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3).

Comment: oh right, so what would you suggest to do, upload a default to image server eg. amazon s3?

Comment: I don't have a file by that name app/assets/images/:style in  my pipeline

Comment: you have to create one file called *missing.png* - e.g. to link to the default user-icon. If you are using different styles (sizes, like *thumb* or *large*), the `:style` parameter gives you the possibility to choose the right size. Your `:default_url` should then look like `/images/thumb/missing.png` and of course you have to create the folders for each style (size) as well.

Comment: didn't work, application error, at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Comment: My answers were - as your question - very **abstract**. If you need more detailed info, either start a new question for that, or provide some more information to your question like: 1) what gem are you using for uploading? 2) add model code for uploading definition 3) Post the complete error messages. Else there is no way helping you out.

Comment: So i'm using paperclip gem - class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
 :default_url => "/images/medium/alien.jpeg"
 belongs_to :user
end - is my model code - and here's the error message from heroku logs - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': /app/app/models/pin.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
  :default_url => "/images/medium/alien.jpeg" -(pointing to the arrow)

Comment: forget the missing.png line thats not there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45685/discussion-between-ernd-enson-and-spencer-hire)