# Routing error for images Ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I run my app locally on 3000 and all is fine, but when i upload to heroku it is sub standard.
I am using paperclip gem, 
my Heroku logs issues this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):,
```

There seems to be no path to this instance in my pipeline, If it runs locally and not in heroku i figure it's a Heroku config problem?.

Comment: I really don't like these people who ask a question multiple times (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226623/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-images-medium-missing-p) and never come back to it again or accept any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `heroku` you have to additionally use the [aws-sdk gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) like shorlty described in the excellent [paperclip-intro](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage).

Sample configuration:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Best info point is usually heroku itself, see this [example configuration guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

Answer (score 0):

paperclip gem means you are uploading images, and want to access the image via that GET request right?

that path looks like it is for the heroku server itself. Heroku doesn't support file uploads, get amazon s3 setup or some other storage facility.

it works locally because your local setup allows for file uploads and storage.

Comment: i just can't see that request anywhere in my app